# Avoid bundling specific modules with Browserify

Tags: javascript, node.js, browserify

I have a dependency tree like this:

```
index.js
      \__ A
      \__ B
          \__ C
          |   \__ D
           \__ E
```

I want to bundle `index.js` and that works fine: `browserify --node index.js -o bundle.js`

The problem is when one of the dependencies has a dependency. Let's suppose it's `D` that has a native dependency (C++ code).

I want to install it manually using `npm install D` and make the `bundle.js` to really require it from the disk, not from the `bundle.js` code.

How can I exclude the `D` module from the bundle and make the bundle to require it from the `node_modules`?

I tried using `--ignore D`, but it returns an empty object when required.

How can I `require` a real module from the `node_modules` directory (the way like Node's `require` does?

Comment: What's the point of doing this?

Comment: @Vohuman Basically I have some that is not really public *yet* and I want to create a babelified and minified bundle containing all this code. But the code is for the server side (that's why I use the `--node` flag). I just want to ignore the `D` module which is or uses native dependencies and install it using `npm install`. Is it a little bit clearer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `--exclude` option together with `--node`:

```
browserify --node -s GlobalVariable your-script.js -o bundle.js --exclude some-dependency
```

This will create the `bundle.js` file which will define the `GlobalVariable` variable if there is no CommonJS environment.

`--node` is a handy option if you want to run the bundle in Node, not in the browser.

The `--exclude` option will exclude the `some-dependency` module from the output bundle.

Check out the [Browserify Usage](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify#usage) section.